# Empty field "\"\"" In CSV Import Problem

Tags: import, csv-format

I have a huge CSV data, with the format like this:

```
"5";"8";"2803";
"";"6";"2793";
```

I import the data with this code:

```
Import["data.csv", "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> ";"];
```

**The problem is:**
Due to the empty string `""` the table structure is broken: the cell is removed. To fix that, I need to manually edit the file. I replace the empty String `""` with anything like `"0"`:

```
"5";"8";"2803";
"0";"6";"2793";
```

Is there any option to deal with this? To consider `""` as the real element?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Option `"RepeatedSeparators" -> False` solves the problem:

```
file = "\"5\";\"8\";\"2803\";
\"\";\"6\";\"2793\";";

ImportString[file, "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> ";", "RepeatedSeparators" -> False]
```

> ```
> {{5, 8, 2803, ""}, {"", 6, 2793, ""}}
> ```

Although I would consider the default behavior as a bug: the element `""` (substring `"\"\""` of the whole file) shouldn't be interpreted as an absence of a field, it is just an empty string `""` which is a perfectly valid field!

Comment: Thank you Alexey!